# Заставить персонажа выключить анимацию ходьбы когда он упирается в коллайдер

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно сделать, чтобы когда персонаж переставал двигаться, выключалась анимация ходьбы. Представим что за анимацию отвечает bool AnimPers, мне надо присвоить ему значение false, когда персонаж натыкается на стену и **перестает перемещаться**. Скажите пожалуйста сам принцип, как это можно реализовать. Спасибо

```
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 direction;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        direction.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        direction.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
     rb.MovePosition(rb.position + direction * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);   


    }
```

Comment: Рассчитывай дельту перемещения(то, что в fixedupdate у тебя), кастуй коллайдер в эту позицию, рассчитывай среднюю нормаль среди всех соприкосновений, если нормаль в норме, двигай персонажа, если нет, не двигай. Когда какую анимацию воспроизводить, думаю понятно.

Comment: Нормаль можно пропустить, если вид игры сверху и ходить по какой-то поверхности персонаж не должен. Тогда просто каст коллайдера.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(direction.x == 0 && direction.y == 0){
animator.SetBool("AnimPers",false);
}
```

как то так а вообще глянь вот видео [тык](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6J6-7MV6nrA) и уже изходя из увиденного думаю ты сообразишь что да как. Тебе если в кратце нужно отследить direction.x и direction.у и если они = 0 то вырубаешь анимацию движения

Comment: Если у него персонаж наткнется на стену то direction не будет нулевым и анимация не закончится. "Важно не забывать делать комментарии в скрипте, чтобы потом не тупить перед экраном" По этой фразе и дальнейшему комментированию чуть ли не каждой строки, можно понять уровень "учителя" из этого видео. Исходя из этого видео он ничего не сообразит, максимум сообразит как скопипастить их костыльный код. Даже при создании джойстика, они просто скопировали код из готового бесплатного ассета и не смогли объянить что делает "огромное условие", просто сказав, что "кому надо, тот посмотрит в документации".